# Dynamic appending constraints in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL

```
SELECT devudp1.deviceoid,devudp1.valueType
  FROM DeviceUdpValues devUDP1 
 WHERE devudp1.udpname='TestUDP' 
   and <<either bdvalue or string value based on user selected value datatype>>
```

Here in the Query based on the **devudp1.valueType** I want to append below attribute

If the valueType is 3 then I want to append my above select clause with **devudp1.bdvalue ='10'**, else it should be appended by **devudp1.bdvalue = 'Hello'**

So the above query when valueType is 3 will look like

```
SELECT devudp1.deviceoid,devudp1.valueType
  FROM DeviceUdpValues devUDP1
 WHERE devudp1.udpname='TestUDP'
   AND devudp1.bdvalue = '10'
```

else it will look like

```
SELECT devudp1.deviceoid,devudp1.valueType
  FROM DeviceUdpValues devUDP1
 WHERE devudp1.udpname='TestUDP'
   AND devudp1.stringValue = 'Hello'
```

Can anyone suggest me how to put this logic in place

Comment: This sort of thing is a bad idea.  It might make life easier for the developer but it tends to punish the user with poor performance,

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT  devudp1.deviceoid,devudp1.valueType
  FROM  DeviceUdpValues devUDP1 
 WHERE  devudp1.udpname='TestUDP'
   AND  (
         (<USER-SELECTED-VALUE> = 3 AND devudp1.bdvalue ='10') OR
         (<USER-SELECTED-VALUE> <> 3 AND devudp1.stringvalue ='Hello') 
        )
```